# When does someone become an orphan?

Tags: halacha

At what age is someone considered an orphan when his/her parent(s) die? For example, what if a 90 year old's parents die. Does he have the status of an orphan? What about a 20 year old?

Comment: For what purpose or context are you asking? A person feels the pain of the death of his parents no matter what age he may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://outorah.org/p/26410/) site,

> They [are] considered orphans for the purposes of this mitzvah until they no longer require an adult to take care for them and they can handle their own affairs like other adults.